# send array values in afnetworking post method

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, afnetworking

to be sended in this format `[@"language":@"English",@"language":@"Tamil"]`

Tried this

```
 NSArray *test=@[@"English",@"Tamil"];
 NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

 NSInteger noselectedlangu= [test count];
 int i;

for(i=0;i<noselectedlangu;i++)
{
    [dict setObject:test[i] forKey:@"language"];
}

 NSLog(@"params : %@", dict);
```

Result:`language=Tamil`

so only the last value comes can any guide me in to the correct direction

Comment: You should send comma separated string with all language.

Comment: when you store value for same key in dictionary ... it will be override in dictionary not makes a whole new key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this output then use below it maybe help but you have to access it using array

```
NSArray *test=@[@"English",@"Tamil"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSInteger noselectedlangu= [test count];
int i;
for(i=0;i<noselectedlangu;i++)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [dic setObject:test[i] forKey:@"language"];
    [arr insertObject:dic atIndex:0];
    [dict setObject:arr forKey:@"languages"];
}
NSLog(@"params : %@", dict);
```

Comment: thanks for your response but i should insert the dict in the parameters @"languages":@[dict]

Comment: can you provide a solution some thing like this @"language":@"English",@"language":@"Tamil"

Comment: there is no option to display same key in a disctionary, Why are you not try in array? @kirankumar

Comment: how can i make some thing like this in an array

Comment: you have to add every dictionary(of language) in one array. Is it convenient? otherwise you have to change on api side.

Answer (score 1):

Its happening due to because dictionary store only one value for a key. If you are going to save another value with same key then it will replace last value which you set on dictionary.

**Example:**

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [dict setObject:@"Hindi" forKey:@"language"];

NSLog(@"Dic Value %@", dict);
```

**Output:** Hindi

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
 [dict setObject:@"Hindi" forKey:@"language"];
 [dict setObject:@"English" forKey:@"language"];

NSLog(@"Dic Value %@", dict);
```

**Output:** English

You can see Hindi is replaced by English because we are using same key.

Hope you can understand it very well now.

You can store like this

```
for(i=0;i<noselectedlangu;i++)
{
    NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"language%d",i];
    [dict setObject:test[i] forKey:key];
}


NSLog(@"Dinctionary %@",dict);
```

Comment: I understand the problem but how can i fix this @Dharmbir Singh

Comment: @kirankumar see my edited answer. You can store like this.

Comment: it should has the same key and the key should not be changed

Comment: In that case you can send array of language in **language** key

Comment: than it will be some thing like this Language:english,hindhi..... the api is not accepting some thing like this

Comment: Yes, it would be like this but if the api can accept then what we can we do. In that you have to find out the soulution.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,
in my app pass data in array like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

[dict setObject:@"English" forKey:@"language[0]"];
[dict setObject:@"Hindi" forKey:@"language[1]"];
```

pass dict in parameter.